# Mapping Based on Value of JSON Response in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit

The REST service I am consuming has two different modes of a response.

```
{
success: true,
data: { //all data goes here}
}
```

or

```
{
success: false,
error: "Error",
message: "some message"
}
```

I'm trying to configure RESTKit to return a certain error object I've created to store the error response and a configured class (based on URL) for the success=true case.

I'm trying to use a RKDynamicMapping to accomplish this based on the value of "success".

```c
   - (RKDynamicMapping *)createCompatibleMapping:(NSDictionary *)successDictionary  withClass:(Class) class{
        NSMutableDictionary *withSuccessDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:successDictionary];
        [withSuccessDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:@{@"success" : @"success"}];

    RKObjectMapping *successMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:class];
    [successMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:withSuccessDictionary];

    RKObjectMapping *restErrorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RESTErrorObject class]];
    [restErrorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"success" : @"success", @"error" : @"errorString", @"message" : @"message"}];

    RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [RKDynamicMapping new];


    [dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"success" expectedValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES ] objectMapping:successMapping]];
    [dynamicMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"success" expectedValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO ] objectMapping:restErrorMapping]];
    return dynamicMapping;
}
```

I then add it to a response descriptor like such:

```
RKResponseDescriptor * cardDetailsResponseDescriptor2  = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:cardDetailsResponseMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                                    pathPattern:@"services/details/:cardNumber" keyPath:@"data"
                                                                                                    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[_objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"getCardDetailsRoute" pathPattern:@"services/details/:cardNumber" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
```

I then call

```
[self.objectManager getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:@"getCardDetailsRoute" object:card parameters:@{@"token" : authToken} success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
```

I know this is a big post and may be hard to understand. I appreciate your patience :D
So confused on what I should do.

Changing the REST API isn't really an option.

Comment: What is `cardDetailsResponseMapping`? The response descriptor should be using `dynamicMapping`.

Comment: cardDetailsResponseMapping is a dynamic mapping.

Comment: 'a' dynamic mapping, different to the one you showed in the code?

Comment: The one being returned there is the one I am using :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the expected value to @"true" @"false". I think that the values will be strings at the time the dynamic mapping is run and that they will only be converted to BOOLs during mapping and if the destination type is a BOOL.